# I am getting Some error when using File in System.IO Ambiguity namespace

Tags: file, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, filestream, system.io.file

I am trying to use 2 Dll refrence on Vs 2015.

Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint

```
' Create a Text File
Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim fs As FileStream = Nothing
    If (Not File.Exists(fileLoc)) Then
        fs = File.Create(fileLoc)
        Using fs

        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Its giving me an error on this portion saying
'File' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.IO, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client'.

```
If (Not File.Exists(fileLoc)) Then
    fs = File.Create(fileLoc)
    Using fs

    End Using
End If
```

How will I create a file?

Comment: Please try like this.                                                                If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(fileLoc)) Then
                            fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileLoc)
                            Using fs

                            End Using
                      End If

Comment: Thanks it worked